# IQ Block Country - Change country param while locked out

Tags: wordpress, security, plugins, maxmind

### Problem

I have current version: IQ Block Country Version 1.1.43

So I had blocked all countries except my home country, but then I moved.
I wanted to be able to login to my word press site without having to resort to options such as:

- VPN to change IP to other country
- proxy server
- teamviewer/remote to other contry

I wanted a way to disable IQ country, change the geo setting, and then login again normally.

I renamed the plugin, in the plugin directory and was able to login to my backend (instead of being redirected). However, when I renamed the plugin again I was kicked off the site again.

**Question:** I was looking in the database but could not found where the country settings are stored. Where would a wordpress plugin store this data?

### Current Workaround

I went to the file: `iq-block-country/libs/blockcountry-checks.php` via FTP.
and I found where the function doing the block checking exists.

Then set $blocked to false, before returning.

```
//MINOR HACK
$blocked = FALSE;
return $blocked;
```

Following I was able to edit the list of countries, and then commented out the `$blocked = FALSE;`

I would like though to be able to do it through PHPAdmin if I travel and this happens again.

Comment: Would you like to consider another alternative, like https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/ip2location-country-blocker? Features are comparable, but it allows you to customize the secret code to bypass the blocking in case of your traveling.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the option blockcountry_blockbackend from your wp_options table next time. And then login again and set your backend blocking options again.